# VSCode + Flutter + Dart => Rename Symbol is really slow and sometimes not even working

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Rename symbol (shortcut key F2) in my flutter projects is really slow. Not sure if flutter is relevant of if this is a general dart problem. When I have syntax/build errors I find it common that rename never finishes, the "infinite progress" in VS Code just keeps spinning what seems to be forever.

If I create a brand new project: `flutter create slow_refactor` and then open the project, let everything initialize, pub get packages and then let it complete. After this I go to main.dart, rename `title` to `myTitle`. This takes ... 10? 15? seconds to complete. If I rename it to `myTitle2` it takes a split second.

Can I mitigate this issue somehow? It's really tedious to rename symbols and most often I just hit replace all feature instead because I'm convinced that the rename won't work. Rename is such a common (simple) refactor that I expect it to work at all times.

I can't find any known issues regarding this but I know that other members in my team have the same issue.

I'm running Windows 10, stable VS Code, flutter 1.13 and 1.14 (beta and master), dart 2.8.0-dev.3.0. My computer specs are category "great" so this is not due to slow cpu, disk or memory issues.

Comment: I recommend raising this issue in the GitHub repo instead: https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues

Comment: Thanks, raised an issue there as well. Will post answer here if it's answered on github. https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2231